# Tile Size remains the same as default which is [256,256] in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

I am trying to add a custom layer using XYZ source on the Open Street Map. I want to add it to a certain coordinate. I want to change the tile size to a different value than the default value. I am not able to change the tile Size to any value.
After numerous attempts I added `tileGrid` and it gives me `Assertion Error`. Am i missing something.

```
 let map = new Map({
    target: 'map-container',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM()
        }),
    new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'assets/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            wrapX: false,
            tileGrid: new TileGrid({
            tileSize: [1024,512]
          })                                                                                                                     
       }),
          tileSize: [1024,512]              

        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: [0,0],
        zoom:0,
        minZoom: 0,
      })
```

Comment: TileGrid also needs extent and resolutions.  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-custom-tilegrid-512x256.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because the files that i have were [256,256], to increase the size must have equal to greater to the size you want.